# System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name 'ApplicationRoleId'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I'm working on my project it's based on ASP.net Core 2.0. I've created `ApplicationRole` and `ApplicationUser` class. I've wrote a snippet code for making roles when I run my project I've got this error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Invalid column name
>   'ApplicationRoleId'.

But the same code that I use in ASP.net Core 1.1 didn't have any problem.

I think it has a problem with this line of code:

> `lineNumberOfUsers =  r.Users.Count`

Because when I comment this code project works fine, but *I need count of users for every role.*

**Controller:**

```
public class ApplicationRoleController : Controller
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly RoleManager<ApplicationRole> _roleManager;

    public ApplicationRoleController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {    
        List<ApplicationRoleViewModel> models = new List<ApplicationRoleViewModel>();
        models = _roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new ApplicationRoleViewModel
        {

            Id = r.Id,
            Name = r.Name,
            Description = r.Description,
            NumberOfUsers =  r.Users.Count 
        }).ToList();
        return View(models);
    }
}
```

**Model**

```
public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole
{
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUser> Users { get; } = new List<ApplicationUser>(); 
}
```

I've checked sql query in sql server profiler. when i ran sql query in sql server I got the same error.

> Invalid column name 'ApplicationRoleId'.

```
SELECT [r].[Id], [r].[Name], [r].[Description], (
    SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM [AspNetUsers] AS [a]
    WHERE [r].[Id] = [a].[ApplicationRoleId]
) AS [NumberOfUsers]
FROM [AspNetRoles] AS [r]
```

Comment: Could you check the exact SQL query in the SQL Profiler to know the failing SQL statement?

Comment: yes,I've checked sql query in sql server profiler. I've added it in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation property `Users` in your `ApplicationRole` class isn't needed.

The relationship between `AspNetUsers` and `AspNetRoles` tables is present in a separate table `AspNetUserRoles` as foreign keys. So, when you want to query the number of users in a given role, you need to interrogate that table `AspNetUserRoles`. In order to achieve that you can call

```
_userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("roleName").Result.Count;
```

To do that, implement your Index action method like this:

```
public IActionResult Index()
{    
  List<ApplicationRoleViewModel> models = new List<ApplicationRoleViewModel>();
  models = _roleManager.Roles.Select(r => new ApplicationRoleViewModel
        {
            Id = r.Id,
            Name = r.Name,
            Description = r.Description
            // notice I am not assigning NumberOfUsers here.See further down...
        }).ToList();

        foreach(var m in models)
        {
          m.NumberOfUsers = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync(m.Name).Result.Count;
        }
        return View(models);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I spend a lot of time for finding answer. you save my life.Thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help you!